# TCP/IP chat client server application register user

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I'm writing chat server-client application (mulit-users). I have communication between users, you need to type other user IP address and port number to send message for specific user. Now I want to make that users write user name instead IP address and port number for receiver user.

On server side I have list in which I add every client that is connected on server.
Because this list is list of Socket object, I need advice how to make that on server with client IP address and port number can add unique user name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply tweak your server to include each client's name alongside its Socket object in the list, by having the list store instances of a struct/class instead of just the Sockets by themselves.

When a client connects, require that it sends a unique name to the server, and have the server store that name in the list with that client's Socket (if the name already exists in the list, disconnect the old or new client, your choice).

Then, whenever the server receives a message with a recipient name, it can locate that name in the list and forward the message to the associated client Socket.